# Hibernate Many-To-Many HQL and Creiteria

Tags: hibernate

I have the following scenarios:

```
USERS   1.1   ROLE   \*.\*   MODULE   \*.\*   INTERFACE
```

A single user "JOHN" has one role and the role has multiple modules and the single module has multiple interfaces. I have used the annotaion in hibernate that works well. When I get the user object I get the Role and by using the role object I get the list of modules and in module object I get the the interfaces.

In simple when I get the user I get the interfaces that contain the user but how may I get the interfaces which are not pertains with the user through HQL & Criteria. e.g

I fetch the interface data IN and NOT IN by SQL but I want to get the data by using  HQL & Criteria.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

IN and NOT IN are supported in HQL as well. In HQL...

To find out all interfaces pertaining to a user, given a user id:

```
select ui from USERS u join u.role.module.interface ui where u.id =:userId;
```

To find out all interfaces **not** pertaining to a user, given a user id:

```
select i from INTERFACE i where i NOT IN (select ui from USERS u join u.role.module.interface ui where u.id =:userId);
```